# angular jasmine test with toHaveBeenCalled

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for the following function:

```
onNextClick() {
    this.toast.clear();

    let checkedSubservices = new Array<number>();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.subSevices.length; i++) {
        if (this.subSevices[i].checked) {
            checkedSubservices.push(this.subSevices[i].id);
        }
    }

    if (checkedSubservices.length > 0)
    {
        this.bookService.setSubserviceIds(checkedSubservices);
        this.stepService.getNextStepByController(StepControllerNames.AllocationStepController)
            .then((ret: StepControllerReturnInfo) => {
                this.goToControllerTarget(ret);
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Error
            });
    }
    else
    {
        let options = { positionClass: 'toast-top-center', preventDuplicates: true };
        this.toast.error("Error.", "", options);
    }
}
```

I want to test that the `goToControllerTarget` has been called. So I have created the following test:

```
it('onNextClick a service is checked', fakeAsync(() => {
    let ret = new ReturnInfo();

    let services = new Array<any>();
    services.push({id: 1, title: "Tite 1"});
    services.push({id: 2, title: "Tite 2"});
    services.push({id: 3, title: "Tite 3"});

    component.subSevices = services;
    const spy = spyOn(stepService, "getNextStepByController").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(ret));
    const spy2 = spyOn(component, "goToControllerTarget");

    // Test Function
    component.onNextClick();
    tick(0);

    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

The test fails as the `goToControllerTarget` function doesn't get called. I've debugged and the catch code path is called instead of the then.

Comment: `this.stepService.getNextStepByController` returns a promise. You will have to resolve the promise before expecting 'toHaveBeenCalled'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day! I suppose it should work:

```
expect(spy2.calls.any()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: In my personal opinion this would be more appropriate. `expect(spy2).and.callThrough()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Angular tests fail to call a certain service function because the component is not defined correctly. If the service is listed as a provider in the Angular component and not defined in `app.module.ts` then the test may fail:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  providers: [
    MyService,
 ]
})
```

In this case mocking the service in the test does not work..

```
it('should not work', async(inject([MyService], (myService) => {
  ..
  spyOn(myService, 'save').and.returnValue(Observable.of(someCalculation));
```

..and we have to add the services to `app.module.ts` and remove them from the list of providers to make it work.